# Cannot Connect To Managed MySQL Database on DigitalOcean using DOT.NET Core on Visual Studio 17

Tags: mysql, ado.net

I am using .net core and MySQL server which is deployed on digitalocean. I am not able to connect from my local project to the database getting the below error.

Access denied for user 'username'@'ipaddress' (using password: NO)

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Use the correct username and password in the connection string. As the [MySQL docs show](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html) the connection string should look like `"server=127.0.0.1;uid=myAccount;pwd=12345;database=test"`

Comment: I have already added connection string like that only

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.